# How can I change the Flutter default time selection widget text?

Tags: flutter

[image]
How can I change the text in the cancel and ok button in the time picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `hack` the official `TimePicker` widget. You will find the code in the `customTimePicker.dart` file, see below. I have changed it from 'OK' to 'BINGO'. Search for *bingo* in that file. Feel free to edit things to get more dynamic UI.

The code is huge. I couldn't add it here.

[Check it on github.](https://github.com/Amonc/flutter-custom-time-picker/tree/master/lib)

[image]